# Reload required file in rails console not using !reload?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, console

I am working with a .rb function in my rails root directory in order to learn rails/ruby. I am finding this the best way possible to learn, however I am finding it very time consuming because every time I change my function I need to exit the rails console completely ('exit'), then reload rails console ('rails c'), then require my .rb file again... otherwise changes to my .rb file are not reflected within the console. I have tried '!reload' inside the console, but this doesn't seem to reload the function that I'm playing with. Also if I simply type 'require' and the filename again rails responds 'false' and the changes in the .rb file are not reflected at the console.

Thanks for your help,
Abram

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question...

I've tried this in pry and worked, I suppose that's the same in irb

require 'my_file' # it was at app/models/my_file.rb

then I used load 'app/models/my_file.rb' and it thrown nil

but the file was reloaded anyway... I don't know exactly what
happened.. this is the documentation for load http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Kernel.html#method-i-load

If anyone can explain this behavior better it would be great

Comment: I had read that you have to include the relative path to the file... but it works with just the name of the file + extension

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. I think it should work after running:

> load 'myfile'

It worked for me.